# Converting string to Bulleted List in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got the following string while studying Chapter 6: Manipulating Strings in 'Automate the Boring Stuff with Python' by AI Sweigart:

```
text = '''Lists of animals
Lists of aquarium life
Lists of biologists by author abbreviation
Lists of cultivars'''
```

I am expected to convert the string to a bulleted list.

I have split the string using new line as the separator, according to the author's guidelines, then append the list into an empty list. Thereafter, I added bullets to the beginning of each item using the following code:

```
lines = text.split('\n')
textList = []
for x in lines:
    textList.append(x)
for y in textList:
    newList = '* ' + y
print(newList)
```

Then the result I got is:

- Lists of cultivars

Which is the last item in the list. Whereas, the author wants the list to appear as follows:

- Lists of animals
- Lists of aquarium life
- Lists of biologists by author abbreviation
- Lists of cultivars

Please I need help on how to achieve this in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```py
text = "\n".join(["* " + substr for substr in text.split("\n")])
```

This adds an asterisk to every line in `text` by splitting `text` by newlines, adding an asterisk and then joining them with a newline in between.

Output:

```
* Lists of animals
* Lists of aquarium life
* Lists of biologists by author abbreviation
* Lists of cultivars
```

However, if you want the text as a list of lines instead of a text block, you just omit the `"\n".join()`:

```py
text = ["* " + substr for substr in text.split("\n")]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This second suggestion works and does exactly what I want. Thanks a lot. i.e. text = ["* " + substr for substr in text.split("\n")]. What I then added to display the list line by line is 
'for elem in text:
      print(elem)'
I didn't know list comprehension would work on it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the regular expression to search for the beginning of each line and insert the asterisks.

```py
import re

text = '''Lists of animals
Lists of aquarium life
Lists of biologists by author abbreviation
Lists of cultivars'''

text = re.sub(r"^", "* ", text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```